# How to animate a texture (sequentially show image textures) in Cycles?

Tags: animation, texturing, materials, image

I have 14 PNG images that I need to animate (show) sequentially on a plane material in Cycles. What options do I have?

I figured 2 solutions, but they are rather cumbersome workarounds.

Solution 1: I made 14 Plane objects - duplicates, each with a new material with the next PNG texture in the sequence, and I sequentially keyframe their visibility on and off in the Outliner.

Solution 2: Perhaps I could prepare one large texture, with all the PNGs beside each other in a row, and then animate the Mapping node X location.

Isn't there anything simpler? I tried animating the image name in the Image Texture Node, but it won't do it. Can't animate the image name.

I know I could just animate the visibility checkbox next to each texture right in the Texture Panel of the Plane in Blender Internal, but I need the same simple solution in Cycles.

Note: I don't need any fancy effect to it, just plain visibility On/Off functionality.

Comment: Have you tried loading them as an image sequence?

Comment: I could load them up as Image sequence but then they will play back 1 image per frame, and in this particular case I need sometimes 2-3-4 frames in between. I could use a workaround - prepare the necessary duplicates of the PNGs with subsequent names and play them back at 1 image per frame, but it is again cumbersome and inflexible.

Comment: How about renaming the pictures accordingly? just rename the same photo for the number of frames you need them to show?